# Plot multiple lines in transparent gray such that overlapping parts are darker

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, matlab, ggplot2

Unfortunately I cannot remember where I saw it, so I cannot provide a picture of how the plot should look like. I can just describe it:

Do you know a way in MATLAB or R to plot multiple time series in transparent gray, such that overlapping parts are darker? The more lines overlap, the closer the respective part should go to black.

Comment: In most systems this is done with transparency settings.  In `R`, look for arguments named `alpha` in color-definition functions like `hsv`, `gray`, *etc.*  You can also specify transparency (in many cases) using a four-byte hexadecimal string where the fourth byte (last two hex digits) gives the degree of transparency.  For instance, `"#ff000080"` is red (($R,G,B)=(ff_H,0_H,0_H)=(255,0,0)$) with transparency value $80_H/ff_H\approx 0.5.$

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! I did indeed find the alpha argument in MATLAB. In particular we can edit the 'MarkerEdgeAlpha' and 'MarkerFaceAlpha' argument in a scatterplot. Unfortunately for a normal plot only the line transparancy and NOT the marker transparency can be changed.